# Cannot redirect after facebook login using response entity in spring boot

Tags: java, facebook, spring-boot, http, redirect

Ok, so I am trying to achieve facebook authentication in my application but after success user is not redirected to homepage even though location header is set.

This is my current scenario.
Front-End call:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/login/facebook")
  public String loginFacebook() {
    String facebookLoginUrl = String.valueOf(this.restTemplate.getForEntity(this.serverApi + "/login/facebook",String.class).getHeaders().get("Location"));
    facebookLoginUrl = facebookLoginUrl.substring(1,facebookLoginUrl.length()-1);
    System.out.println(facebookLoginUrl);
    return "redirect:" + facebookLoginUrl;
  }
```

Back-End:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/facebook", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String startFacebookProcess() {
        this.facebookConnectionFactory = new FacebookConnectionFactory(appId,appSecret);

        OAuth2Operations operations = this.facebookConnectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
        OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
// promeni url-a za front-enda
        parameters.setRedirectUri("http://localhost:8080/login/returnFromFacebook");
        parameters.setScope(this.scope);
        System.out.println("In startFacebookProcess");
        String url = operations.buildAuthorizeUrl(parameters);
        System.out.println(url);
        return "redirect:" + url;
    }
```

After that, the user is being redirected to the official facebook login page where he allows his details to be used.

Then he performs a GET request to my Front-End with his authorization code:

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/login/returnFromFacebook")
  public ResponseEntity getFacebookData(@RequestParam("code") String authorizationCode){
    System.out.println(authorizationCode);
       ResponseEntity response = this.restTemplate.getForEntity(this.serverApi +
         "/login/returnFromFacebook?code=" + authorizationCode, ResponseEntity.class);
       if(response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()){
         return response;
       }
           return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);

  }
```

My Back-End is being called and I contact facebook to fetch the user data using his authorization code. Then I return a ResponseEntity which inherited all the HttpServletResponse headers and cookies.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/returnFromFacebook", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity getDataFromFacebook(@RequestParam("code") String authorizationCode,
                                              HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // leg 2
        OAuth2Operations operations = this.facebookConnectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
       AccessGrant accessGrant = operations.exchangeForAccess(authorizationCode,
               "http://localhost:8080/login/returnFromFacebook",null);
       // leg 3
        System.out.println("code: " + authorizationCode);
        Connection<Facebook> connection = this.facebookConnectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
        User currentUser = connection.getApi().fetchObject("me", User.class,"email,first_name,last_name");
        System.out.println("Email: " + currentUser.getEmail());

        if(this.appUserDAO.findUserAccountByEmail(currentUser.getEmail()) == null){
            Map<String, String> facebookDetailsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            facebookDetailsMap.put("email",currentUser.getEmail());
            facebookDetailsMap.put("name",currentUser.getFirstName() + " " + currentUser.getLastName());
            this.appUserDAO.saveFacebookAccount(facebookDetailsMap);
        }
// Create JWT Token
        String token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(currentUser.getEmail())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JwtProperties.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(HMAC512(JwtProperties.SECRET.getBytes()));
        JwtAuthenticationFilter.setJwtCookie(response,token);
        System.out.println(response.getStatus() + " " + response.getHeader("set-cookie"));
        response.setHeader("Location", "http://localhost:8080/");
//        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
//        headers.add(index");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

This is the received response header in the browser. The cookies are set and everything but user is not being redirected to Location header. :

[image]

I tried to return a String "redirect:/" from GetFacebookData(Front-End) but the response cookies and headers are not being applied. I don't know why the Location header is not working.

Comment: any reason to why you are not using the already prebuilt facebook login providers in spring security? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-common-oauth2-provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by returning the 'index' template if the back-end call was sucessful but also apply the cookie header into the original response (which was to the front-end) using HttpServletResponse (this is not possible with ResponseEntity btw). With HttpServletResponse you dont have to return it to the browser, it applies everything by default. With ResponseEntity you have to return ResponseEntity Object in order to apply headers. This is how the function looks like now:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/login/returnFromFacebook")
  public String getFacebookData(@RequestParam("code") String authorizationCode, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(authorizationCode);
       ResponseEntity response = this.restTemplate.getForEntity(this.serverApi +
         "/login/returnFromFacebook?code=" + authorizationCode, ResponseEntity.class);
    System.out.println(response.getStatusCodeValue() + " " + response.getHeaders().get("Location"));

    //set cookie for original request
    String jwtCookieHeader = String.valueOf(response.getHeaders().get("set-cookie"));
    jwtCookieHeader = jwtCookieHeader.substring(1,jwtCookieHeader.length()-1);

    httpServletResponse.setHeader("set-cookie", jwtCookieHeader);
       if(response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()){
         return "redirect:/";
       }
           return String.valueOf(new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CONFLICT));
  }
```